# How can I Copy the date value from Column C to Column F for each row that matches criteria?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to create a Google App Script for Sheets that will do the following:

**Copy** Date found in column **C** to column **F** 
**IF**: Date in column **C** is <= **C1**.
**AND**: **E** = "Yes"
**For all rows** in sheet range **A6:F**

Example sheet,

| / | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Mark received if before: | 12/15/2021 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | INVOICE No | CUS No | Invoice Date | JOBamount | PayAtService | Received date |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 12/10/2021 | $15.00 | Yes |  |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | 12/6/2021 | $15.00 | Yes |  |
| 8 | 3 | 21 | 12/14/2021 | $45.00 | Yes |  |
| 9 | 4 | 20 | 12/14/2021 | $15.00 | Yes |  |
| 10 | 5 | 13 | 12/15/2021 | $12.00 | No |  |
| 11 | 6 | 14 | 12/15/2021 | $10.00 | No |  |
| 12 | 7 | 12 | 12/15/2021 | $12.00 | No |  |
| 13 | 9 | 9 | 12/15/2021 | $30.00 | No |  |
| 14 | 10 | 1 | 12/15/2021 | $15.00 | Yes |  |
| 15 | 11 | 18 | 12/15/2021 | $12.00 | No |  |
| 16 | 12 | 17 | 12/15/2021 | $25.00 | No |  |
| 17 | 13 | 15 | 12/15/2021 | $12.00 | Yes |  |
| 18 | 14 | 16 | 12/15/2021 | $20.00 | No |  |
| 19 | 15 | 19 | 12/15/2021 | $30.00 | Yes |  |
| 20 | 16 | 4 | 12/16/2021 | $15.00 | No |  |
| 21 | 17 | 5 | 12/16/2021 | $7.00 | Yes |  |
| 22 | 18 | 6 | 12/16/2021 | $5.00 | Yes |  |
| 23 | 19 | 7 | 12/16/2021 | $7.00 | No |  |
| 24 | 20 | 8 | 12/16/2021 | $6.00 | Yes |  |
| 25 | 21 | 10 | 12/20/2021 | $15.00 | No |  |
| 26 | 22 | 23 | 12/20/2021 | $30.00 | Yes |  |
| 27 | 23 | 13 | 12/29/2021 | $12.00 | Yes |  |
| 28 | 24 | 12 | 12/29/2021 | $12.00 | Yes |  |
| 29 | 26 | 9 | 12/29/2021 | $30.00 | Yes |  |
| 30 | 27 | 15 | 12/29/2021 | $12.00 | Yes |  |
| 31 | 28 | 16 | 12/29/2021 | $20.00 | No |  |
| 32 | 29 | 23 | 12/29/2021 | $30.00 | No |  |

(This seems like it would be simple but haven't quite figured out how)

I tried something like this but I think I am limiting my range (want to all rows in sheet to be in range) and it is also simply full of errors...

```js
function ReceivedDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var vs = sh.getRange(6, 1, 500, 6).getValues() //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) but this needs to be whole sheet from row 6 down
  var cutoffDate = new Date(sh.getRange('F2').getValue());
  
  vs.forEach(row => {
    if (row[5] != 'Yes'  && new Date(row[3]).valueOf() <= cutoffDate) 
      vs(row, 6).setValue(row, 3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function ReceivedDate() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
   var vs = sh.getRange(6, 1, 500, 6).getValues() //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) but this needs to be whole sheet from row 6 down
   var cutoffDate = new Date(sh.getRange('C1').getValue());
   vs.forEach((row,index)=> {
      if (row[4] == 'Yes'  && new Date(row[2]) <= cutoffDate){
            sh.getRange(index+6,6).setValue(row[2]);
        }  
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. how would I change the range to get all rows not just 500 as it is set here?      `vs = sh.getRange(6, 1, 500, 6).getValues()`

Comment: vs = sh.getRange(6, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 6).getValues()

Comment: Perfect. Works!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you want a solution in **AppScript** or just a solution. But for your requirement above, a simple formula as below should work.

```
=IF(AND(DATEVALUE(C6) <= DATEVALUE($C$1), E6 = "Yes"),C6,"")
```

Comment: Thank you. This formula would work and is a great answer but I do need a script as this is part of a larger workflow I am developing...